# How can I extract increasing consecutive values?

Tags: iterator, iteration, data-manipulation

I have a sample array of objects...

```
const entries = [
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/15',
    numSteps: 3577,
    minutesActive: 140,
    flightsOfStairs: 16
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/16',
    numSteps: 6637,
    minutesActive: 175,
    flightsOfStairs: 36
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/17',
    numSteps: 14329,
    minutesActive: 168,
    flightsOfStairs: 18
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/18',
    numSteps: 4419,
    minutesActive: 165,
    flightsOfStairs: 33
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/19',
    numSteps: 8429,
    minutesActive: 275,
    flightsOfStairs: 2
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/20',
    numSteps: 14478,
    minutesActive: 140,
    flightsOfStairs: 12
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/21',
    numSteps: 6760,
    minutesActive: 135,
    flightsOfStairs: 6
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/22',
    numSteps: 10289,
    minutesActive: 119,
    flightsOfStairs: 6
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/23',
    numSteps: 8213,
    minutesActive: 122,
    flightsOfStairs: 27
  },
  {
    userID: 1,
    date: '2019/06/24',
    numSteps: 11654,
    minutesActive: 270,
    flightsOfStairs: 19
  }
]
```

I am trying to find instances of increasing `numSteps` through a for loop, so if there are consecutive days of increasing steps, those days get pushed into a new array. This is my loop...

```
let dates = []

for (var i = 0; i < this.entries.length - 1; i++) {
      if (this.entries[i].numSteps < this.entries[i + 1].numSteps) {
        dates.push(this.entries[i])
      }
    }
```

I am very close to getting this to work, but can't figure out how to push the final value before the condition is met. I should be getting the first three index pushed into the new array, but am only getting two. I see why this is happening, because by the time I hit the third index, the condition in my loop is no longer true. I am just not sure how I can push the indexes that meet the condition and the one directly after that. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `for` loop cover the full range, then enhance the `if` statement to compare with both next and previous.

```
let len = this.entries.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
    if ((i < len - 1 && this.entries[i].numSteps < this.entries[i + 1].numSteps)
     || (i > 0 && this.entries[i - 1].numSteps < this.entries[i].numSteps)) {
        dates.push(this.entries[i])
    }
}
```